# Neo4j:How to get Graph database Metadata?

Tags: metadata, neo4j

I have started working with neo4j graph DB,i would like to know if there is a way to get graph metadata: information like the number of nodes, relationships in the graph etc.

thanks,

Comment: Are you looking for programmatic, or something else?

Comment: hi @Nicholas,i'm looking for anyway to do it, even using cypher or using SDN template

Comment: I don't think those things, but what I meant was does it have to be in code? You can use JMX to access the statistics.

Comment: sorry @Nicholas i misunderstood you, yes this have to be in code. i m trying to do it using jmx; as you mentioned.for now i want to get number of nodes , so i'm trying to get the graphDb service then get the nodeManager and finally the numberOfIdsInUse; but the method that returns nodeManager is deprecated, is there any other way to get this ?. (the neo4j version i use is 1.8.2) Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can access JMX bean as documented on http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-jmx.html. For a reference of beans check out http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/jmx-mxbeans.html.

Comment: thank you @Stefan that is helpful, i'm trying to make it work